# Two DLLs with the same namespace and type with Nuget

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-server

I have two DLLs with different names that I need to use in a project. I'm able to do this using `extern alias` as shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx

This involves changing the alias property of the reference from `global` to some other value within Visual Studio.

The problem is that we started using Nuget package manager and each time a package is updated this property reverts to `global`. Is there a way to get assembly aliases working with Nuget?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use extern alias with nuget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460667/how-to-use-extern-alias-with-nuget)