# How to use extern alias with nuget

Tags: c#, nuget

I use `extern alias` in my project so I need to change the reference alias from `global` to something else. The problem is that if I use Nuget to add the reference, every time I update the package the alias reverts to `global`. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 35):

This is know issue with nuget references; in case of  assembly alias is not supported at all (yet): https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4989

Fortunately workaround exists; you can add special target to your csproj that will assign aliases on-the-fly:

```
  <Target Name="ChangeAliasesOfNugetRefs" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'CoreCompat.System.Drawing'">
        <Aliases>CoreCompatSystemDrawing</Aliases>
      </ReferencePath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Comment: this might be obvious given the question but you reference it with `extern alias CoreCompatSystemDrawing;` above all the usings in your .cs file.

Comment: You've saved me; this is exactly the library I was having issues with.  Thank you.

Comment: It's now supported as of NuGet 5.7 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-5.7

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 100000 times. This has been driving me nuts on an old project

Comment: I still get the error 
The extern alias 'CoreCompatSystemDrawing' was not specified in a /reference option

Answer (score 13):

Starting with NuGet 5.7 & Visual Studio 2019 Update 7, `PackageReference` now [supports the `Aliases` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#packagereference-aliases). There is no UI, but you can edit directly the project file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NuGet.Versioning" Version="5.8.0" Aliases="ExampleAlias" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And then in the C# code:

```cs
extern alias ExampleAlias;

namespace PackageReferenceAliasesExample
{
...
        {
            var version = ExampleAlias.NuGet.Versioning.NuGetVersion.Parse("5.0.0");
            Console.WriteLine($"Version : {version}");
        }
...
}
```

Comment: I love giving new answers to old questions, especially about tricky matters like this. I really thank you for doing it here as this was exactly what I needed. As far as I can tell, there is still no UI in Visual Studio 2022, but the alias still works.

Answer (score 5):

Thank You for the csproj Target to change aliases of assembly references.

I have used it to fix System.Data.Services.Client/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client collision like this one:

> error CS0433: The type 'DataServiceContext' exists in both
>   'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client, Version=5.8.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'System.Data.Services.Client,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

The solution is:

```
  <!--
  Avoid collision of older System.Data.Services.Client with newer Microsoft.Data.Services.Client
  when mixed due to PackageReferences
  -->
  <Target Name="ChangeAliasesOfNugetRefs" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'System.Data.Services.Client'">
        <Aliases>legacy</Aliases>
      </ReferencePath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible because after nuget update it removes the previous assembly and add a new assembly so it removes the assembly with it's alias ... so you must add again your alias to the new updated assembly.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this process?

Comment: you can read more about [**Extend NuGet Command Line**](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_reynolds/archive/2011/07/15/extend-nuget-command-line.aspx) .. maybe it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could add an [install script](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package#automatically-running-powershell-scripts-during-package-installation-and-removal) to your NuGet package to add the alias.  But the consumer of the package would not be able to opt-out of adding the alias.  Here's some code you could use in the script.  I'm not the greatest at powershell so there may be a better way to do it :)

```
# Standard Install.ps1 parameter list
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

# Name of the alias
$alias = 'MyAlias'

# Load the Microsoft.Build assembly to be able to access MS Build types
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Build

# Load the csproj file
$projectObject = New-Object Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project($project.FullName)

# Search through the project items to find all references
$referenceItems = $projectObject.Items | where ItemType -eq "Reference" 

# Find the reference that matches the package id 
# (this assumes your assembly name matches your package id)
$item = $referenceItems | select @{Name='Reference'; Expression={$_}},@{Name='AssemblyName'; Expression={(New-Object System.Reflection.AssemblyName($_.UnevaluatedInclude)).Name}} | where AssemblyName -eq $package.Id | select Reference

# If the reference doesnt already have an alias, add one and save the project
if (($item.Reference.Metadata | where Name -eq 'Aliases') -eq $null) {
    $item.Reference.SetMetadataValue('Aliases', $alias)
    $projectObject.Save()
}

# Unload the project when done
$projectObject.ProjectCollection.UnloadAllProjects()
```