# Same Nuget package on two different projects in same solution

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I have two API projects within the same solution (one in which is mine, and another in which I need to reference and should not be changing). Both of these API projects add reference to the `Ninject` and `Ninject.Web.Common` package. Here is how the packages are setup:

`Ninject.Web.Common` In Web Api A - `\packages\Ninject.Web.Common.3.3.2\lib\net45\Ninject.Web.Common.dll`
`Ninject.Web.Common` in Web Api B - `\packages\Ninject.Web.Common.3.2.3.0\lib\net45-full`

(note the versions are different `3.3.2` and `3.2.3`)

What's happening is when I try to run my solution I get

`Could not load type 'Ninject.Web.Common.OnePerRequestHttpModule' from assembly 'Ninject.Web.Common, Version=3.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7'.`

on my `Web Api B` project (note it's trying to reference the `3.3.2` version from my `Web Api A` project).

How can I keep both projects the same and have them reference their own respective version of Ninject?

Comment: Does `B` have to reference 3.2.3 or you may update package version?

Comment: It has to, or it breaks on the new version

Comment: Then fix the place where it breaks in the new version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one of these approaches:

1. Create post build step which register the multi-versioned assemblies into the GAC.
   The CLR will look in the GAC before checking the output folder. Since both assemblies are installed in the GAC, the runtime will find and load the correct versions.
2. Install both assemblies to the GAC with gacutil.exe. However, it's not very practical for development environments as the installation has to be repeated on every machine.
   Once installed, set the references` CopyLocal property to False, since there’s no need for them to be in the output folder.
3. Perform custom resolution via [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) event.
4. Copy assemblies to different folders and specify [codebase element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/codebase-element?redirectedfrom=MSDN). By editing a web application configuration file, you can point the application to the appropriate DLL versions even if they're not directly in the bin folder.

```
     <configuration>
              <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
                <dependentAssembly>
                  <assemblyIdentity name="SomeStrongNameLib" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="6a770f8bdf3d476a" />
                  <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="StrongNameLibV10/SomeStrongNameLib.dll"/>
                  <codeBase version="1.1.0.0" href="StrongNameLibV11/SomeStrongNameLib.dll"/>
                </dependentAssembly>
              </assemblyBinding>
          </runtime>
        </configuration>
```

5. Use [binding redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions), but I think that this is not suitable in your case.
6. Use [extern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460667/how-to-use-extern-alias-with-nuget) Nuget aliases.

Reference:
[Using two different versions of same the nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802007/using-two-different-versions-of-same-the-nuget-package)
https://michaelscodingspot.com/how-to-resolve-net-reference-and-nuget-package-version-conflicts/
https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/referencing-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly-in-a-single-application

Answer (score 1):

You can typically only resolve one version of a given dependency in your dependency graph (`nuget restore` is mainly for calculating which version to use given your dependency graph).

This is usually fine, but your problem is that `OnePerRequestHttpModule` was removed between versions 3.2.3 and 3.3.2 of Ninject.Web.Common https://www.fuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.Common/3.3.2/lib/netstandard2.0/diff/3.2.3/ and WebApiB wanted to use it.

Your options here are to modify WebApiB so it doesn't use `OnePerRequestHttpModule` any more, or to downgrade the version of Ninject.Web.Common in WebApiA to 3.2.3

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I cannot downgrade my current project and I cannot upgrade the other project... I need more of a work around. There *has* to be a way.

Comment: A possible workaround is to reimplement and replace the class missing in the new version and upgrade. Another is separate solutions and DLL references instead of project references for your APIs

Comment: What Richard said, or instead of reimplementing you can rewrite one of the assemblies so it has a different name and different namespaces with a tool like https://github.com/nullean/assembly-rewriter. These are all nasty solutions though which will almost certainly cause you problems in the future, you're much better off fixing this properly even if it's painful in the short term

Answer (score -1):

I see you are on 4.5 FW but:

If you are already on the newer csproj format or you can upgrade to it (this is just to change the format of csproj, **the project itself will still target what it was targeting**)

https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/

then you could stop the dependecies flowing to the top (the link is for dotnet core, but if the project format is the newer one from above, then the suggestion is still valid):

> The way to change the default behavior is to add

```
<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
```

> for each package/project dependency inclusion.

https://curia.me/net-core-transitive-references-and-how-to-block-them/

this should work also on some Full .Net FW pojects.

Once you managed to stop the flowing of dependencjes you can add to your project your reference to the needed version of your dependency